# C# Regex: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Regex.Match(string)'

Tags: c#, regex

i'm encountering an issue with storing values with RegEx when doing a C# quadratic equation solver. Basically, I want the user to input the equation himself, instead of the program asking for a, b, and c.

Here is what i have:

```
string regEx = @"(-?\d +)x\^ 2([+-]\d +)x([+-]\d +)";

Match match = Regex.Match(regEx);
```

The program is done, except for inputting the values. I get this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Regex.Match(string)'

Any ideas as to what I have to do to store the values? I would like to preferably store them in a double array.

Comment: You should pass the input string as the first argument. `Match match = Regex.Match(input_string, regEx);`

Comment: Check out the documentation on that method. You aren't using it correctly.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Match_System_String_

Comment: You're trying to make a match without an actual input string... it's clear you're missing something. To use that particular function, you need to make the pattern into _a regex object_, and then call the `.Match()` on _that_ to get matches out of an _actual string you're processing._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both a regex and a string to test, like this:

```
var regEx = new Regex(@"(-?\d +)x\^ 2([+-]\d +)x([+-]\d +)");

var match = regEx.Match("string to test");
```

or, if you don't plan to use it more than once you could use the static method like this:

```
var match = Regex.Match("string to test", @"(-?\d +)x\^ 2([+-]\d +)x([+-]\d +)");
```

If you want a collection of matches, rather than just the first one, you can get them like this:

```
var matchCollection = regEx.Matches("string to test");
```

Comment: Side note: Technically, `.Matches("string to test");`doesn't return a *list* of matches. `regEx.Matches("string to test").OfType<Match>().ToList();`

Comment: `\d +` looks *suspicious* (yes, I know that it's from question). It seems that we should remove spaces from the pattern or add `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` option

Comment: Good point, `list` implied the wrong thing. I've edited it to be more generic. I'm not even going to try to debug the regex without a specification.

Comment: sure you don't have to provide a regex (of the unknown purpose), but I think it worth mentioning (`\d +` probably should be put without spaces `\d+`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I extract the values of a, b and c from this though?

Comment: This Regex doesn't help you here, all it does is find strings that look like quadratic equations. (perhaps buried in a paragraph of text). You could write some more RegExs to pick out the values but it's probably easier (and much easier to maintain) to use ordinary string parsing. I'd start with `match.Split('x')` to get an array of the three parts, and use `int.TryParse` to convert them to integers. Have a go, and ask another question if you get stuck.